# Finding the hundreds/thousands/tens figure javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have the following issue:

Lets say I have the number 2382 stored in a variable and I want to store the figures of that number in other variables, for instance I want a = 2, b = 3, c = 8, d = 2. Is there any way I can acomplish this ?

Comment: why not use an array for the result?

Comment: Rather store the digits into an array?

Comment: Because I have to compare the hundreds figure to the tens, and the number size is not known. Thought maybe I could solve this with dividing the number or with the use of remainder.

Answer (score 0):

you can get array of elements from this,
for example:

```
a = 2382
a.toString().split('').map(function(d) { return parseInt(d) } )
//[2, 3, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array for the values, after converting to a string and splitting and then convert the string back to number.

```js
var number = 2382;
    splitted = number.toString().split('').map(Number);

console.log(splitted);
```